# How to set up Micromax AQ5001 (MediaTek processor) for Android Studio development

Tags: android, android-studio, driver

I just installed Android Studio, I need some help setting in setting up my phone for debugging. I downloaded the MTK Driver from http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html. When I go to Device Manager and try to install the MTK Driver, Windows says that "The best driver for your device is already installed."

Could anyone please tell me how to set up my phone for Android development.

Comment: And what is the problem? Is usb debugging enabled on the device?

Comment: "Enable usb debugging" in developer options and connect your phone via usb, you are good to go

Comment: Yes USB debugging is enabled and it is connected in PTP mode. But I'm confused as to which driver to install and how. I downloaded the MediaTek driver listed on the Android developers OEM drivers page, but I'm unable to install it in the Windows Device Manager.

Answer (score 1):

If the best driver is already installed, follow these steps to enable USC Debugging and after that you'll be set to use your device.

1. Go to Settings>About phone.
2. Hit the build number 7 times to unlock developer options.
3. Go to Settings>Developer Options.
4. Enable USB Debugging.

You should be able to see your device on your system by typing the following command in your terminal.

```
adb devices
```

Comment: I did enable USB debugging. And the command prompt doesn't recognize the adb command. But the issue is that I'm not able to install the MediaTek drivers for my device.